# SQL String manupulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to retrieve just full name from following data?
(some have commas, some don't)

```
AddressLine1
ATTN: TIMOTHY HOUSE, Local
ATTN: JODIE OLSEN,
ATTN: PETER MACKENZIE,Ho
ATTN: : ANTHONY ZAMMIT,
ATTN: KATHRYN SIMKUS ,Lo
ATTN: JACK COSIER
ATTN: GREG HUNTER
ATTN: PETER KARAGIANNIS
```

Comment: Full name means `TIMOTHY HOUSE, Local` or `TIMOTHY HOUSE`?

Comment: Hi Popeye, Just TIMOTHY HOUSE

Comment: LEFT, RIGHT, CHARINDEX

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

Comment: Basically, texts after : and before ,

Comment: Also, some data have multiple commas, like: ATT: LAURA BROWN, THE QUARRY,

Answer (score 1):

In think this will help you, after that if you have any issues feel free to ask

```
declare @text varchar(100) = 'ATTN: TIMOTHY HOUSE, Local'
declare @FactorValue varchar(100) = right(@text,CHARINDEX(':',reverse(@text)) - 2)
select case when charindex(',',@FactorValue) > 0 then substring(@FactorValue,0, charindex(',',@FactorValue)) else @FactorValue end as 'Full Name',charindex(',',@FactorValue)
```

Comment: However, some data have multiple commas, like: ATT: LAURA BROWN, THE QUARRY,

Comment: I have made some changes can you please try this

Comment: Hi Sagar,
I have a table [address], where [addressLine1] is column with above data.
I modified your code to fit into the table and column name, but it displays some error.

Comment: Error says: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

I replaced text variable with addressLine1 and updated factorValue and finally, updated select statement.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not the best tool to do string extractions, especially for complicated cases like this.

The trick is to determine the correct positions and cases, then mix and match the cases with the positions and determine the string to be extracted.

Following code is complex and complicated. Therefore it is lengthy and in pieces so the various steps and logic is more visible. The whole logic can be folded and written in one SubString function.
My suggestion is to create a view instead that is then joined in the processing. Decouple the logic and transformation from the extraction itself.

```
CREATE TABLE #SomeData
(
  Line  varchar(100)
)
;
INSERT INTO 
  #SomeData
(
  Line
)
SELECT 'ATTN: TIMOTHY HOUSE, Local'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: JODIE OLSEN,'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: PETER MACKENZIE,Ho'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: : ANTHONY ZAMMIT,'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: KATHRYN SIMKUS ,Lo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: : JACK COSIER'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: GREG HUNTER'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ATTN: PETER KARAGIANNIS'
;
-- position determination
SELECT
  Line,
  -- start of extraction
  StringAfterFirstColon   = Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%: %', Line ) - 1 ),
  LengthAfterFirstColon   = Len( Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) ),
  FirstColonPos           = PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) + 1,
  StartPos                = PatIndex( '%[A-Z]%', Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) ),
  EndPosA                 = PatIndex( '%[,:]%', 
      Right( Line, 
        -- length of overall string
        Len( Line ) 
        -- minus first colon position followed by space
        - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 
        -- a) there is another special character 
        -- minus potential gap from start of leftover string to first letter
        - PatIndex( '%[A-Z]%', Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) )
      ) 
    ),
  EndPosB                 = Len( Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) ),
  -- end of extraction
  NameOnLine =
    PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) 
FROM
  #SomeData
;
WITH
  cteDeterminePos
AS
(
  SELECT
    Line,
    -- start of extraction
    StringAfterFirstColon   = Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ),
    LengthAfterFirstColon   = Len( Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) ),
    FirstColonPos           = PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) + 1,
    StartPos                = PatIndex( '%[A-Z]%', Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) ),
    EndPosA                 = PatIndex( '%[,:]%', 
        Right( Line, 
          -- length of overall string
          Len( Line ) 
          -- minus first colon position followed by space
          - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 
          -- a) there is another special character 
          -- minus potential gap from start of leftover string to first letter
          - PatIndex( '%[A-Z]%', Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) )
        ) 
      ),
    EndPosB                 = Len( Right( Line, Len( Line ) - PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) - 1 ) ),
    -- end of extraction
    NameOnLine =
      PatIndex( '%:%', Line ) 
  FROM
    #SomeData
)
SELECT
  Original.Line AS OriginalLine,
  NameOnLine = SubString( Original.Line,
      -- start from StartPos
      Position.StartPos + Position.FirstColonPos,
      -- end depending on whether there is a trailing bit to be excluded or at end of string
      Position.LengthAfterFirstColon 
        -- take fewer characters to eliminate shifted starting position
        - ( Position.StartPos -1 )
        -- eliminate characters after second colon or comma
        - ( Position.EndPosB - Position.EndPosA ) * Sign( Position.EndPosA )
    )
FROM
  #SomeData AS Original
  INNER JOIN cteDeterminePos AS Position
    ON  Position.Line = Original.Line
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SomeData
;
```

Output:

```
OriginalLine                 NameOnLine 
ATTN: TIMOTHY HOUSE, Local   TIMOTHY HOUSE 
ATTN: JODIE OLSEN,           JODIE OLSEN
ATTN: PETER MACKENZIE,Ho     PETER MACKENZIE
ATTN: : ANTHONY ZAMMIT,      ANTHONY ZAMM
ATTN: KATHRYN SIMKUS ,Lo     KATHRYN SIMKUS
ATTN: : JACK COSIER          JACK COSIER
ATTN: GREG HUNTER            GREG HUNTER
ATTN: PETER KARAGIANNIS      PETER KARAGIANNIS
```

Comment: People are genius. I tested for some data, It worked. I have around 5K data, I will check for all. Thank you so so much.